# How to solve the specified port is in use issue?

Tags: iis, iis-express

While launching an web application it showing the error as "the port is in use".

Answer (score 0):

Try running something like nmap against your server to find out what service is running on that port, then find it and shut it down.   Alternatively, just move the service you are trying to access to another port.